# How do I increase my array size when appending?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a web page that is a simple text input box that allows the user to create an unordered list. The list needs to start from empty and the user can add as many entries as they'd like.

So far I've been successful in the user being able to add a single entry but cannot determine how to increase the entry count for subsequent entries. Should I be using a for loop or the push function?

```
document.querySelector("#btnMap").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    
    let destinations=new Map();
    let ulItems=document.querySelector("#ulItems");
    let txtAdd=document.querySelector("#txtAdd");
    ulItems.innerHTML="";
 
        if (txtAdd.value.length>0) destinations.set(1, txtAdd.value) 
    
        for(let [key,value] of destinations){
            let item=document.createElement("li");
            item.innerText=`${key} - ${value}`;
            ulItems.append(item); 
        }  
    
})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Places I'd Like to Visit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Places I'd Like to Visit</h1>
<div id="places"></div>
<input type="text" id="place">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your provided code examples does not belong together. Please post a real working example.